# MySQL query error "Subquery returns more than 1 row" where update into the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How to update to the same table? i tried to do fraction conversion and update 1 of the rows in the same table but the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Below are the code, (State1 is the table itself, Share field consists of those fraction data like 1/2,1/5 ..)

```
UPDATE State1 set shareresult =(SELECT
  x.Multiplier / x.Divider as Result
from
    (select 
      cast( substr( t.share, 
                    1, 
                    locate('/', t.share) - 1) 
            as decimal) 
        as Multiplier,
      cast( substr( t.Share, 
                    locate('/', t.Share) + 1, 
                    locate( ' ', 
                            concat(t.Share, ' '))) 
            as decimal) 
        as Divider
    from
      State1 t ) x)
```

thanks

Finally, i managed to solve my problem with the code below

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE activity_product_ids AS SELECT x.NumberID, x.Multiplier / x.Divider as Result from (select cast( substr( t.share, 1, locate('/', t.share) - 1) as decimal) as Multiplier, cast( substr( t.Share, locate('/', t.Share) + 1, locate( ' ', concat(t.Share, ' '))) as decimal) as Divider, t.ID as numberID from State1 t) x;

UPDATE State1 a
  JOIN activity_product_ids b
    ON a.ID=b.NumberID
  SET a.shareresult=b.Result;
```

Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: provide a [mre] for your problem, so that we can understand what you try to achieve

Comment: As the message says, `set shareresult = (SELECT /* this is the only sub-query here */)` returned more than a single row. Run that sub-query by itself to see what it returns and work from there.

Comment: The the State1 table ever contains more than 1 row, this will be expected: perhaps there is missing *filter* in the sub-query limiting to the *correct* State1 row to update..

Answer (score 1):

Neither your update statement nor the sub-query has a WHERE clause so it looks like you are trying to update every row with fraction to decimal conversion of every row.

This is a much simpler approach -

```
UPDATE State1
SET shareresult = ROUND(SUBSTRING_INDEX(share, '/', 1) / SUBSTRING_INDEX(share, '/', -1), 2)
WHERE id = 1;
```